# Doxygen: Hide data structures section from the tree view

Tags: c, doxygen

I would like, if it is possible, to hide the data structures section from the tree view on the left.

I'm already grouping the desired structured into a module, but somehow the doxygen is still reporting the structures even in the "data structures section".

Here is an example: the module User Data Type contains the structs 1000tp_write, 1000tp_erase and ifmgnt

[image: structs_in_module]

But these structs are then repeated in the data structures section:

[image: data_structures]

By clicking on the structs into data structures section, I get browsed back to the struct inside the module... So I really would like to not have these structs in the data structures section.

In the doxyfile I couldn't find any command to disable the data structures section from the left menu.

I'm using doxygen 1.8.14, and the software is implemented in c.

Comment: Doxygen 1.8.14 is from December 25, 2017. The current doxygen version is 1.9.8 please try with this version again and when the problem persists please add a small example so the problem can be reproduced and hopefully some advise can be given.